# Error when creating log file in uwsgi ini file using date

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, logfiles

I am trying to deploy my Flask app on Nginx using uWSGI.
I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial to deploy my flask app.
I have the following ini file:
extractor.ini

```
    [uwsgi]
    module = wsgi:app

    master = true 
    processes = 5

    socket = extractor.sock
    chmod-socket = 660

    vacuum = true

    log-date = @(exec://date +%%F-%%H-%%M)
    logdir = /home/rkok/extractor/logs/
    daemonize = %(logdir)uwsgi-%(log-date).log

    die-on-term = true
```

However when I try to start my project using

```
sudo systemctl start extractor
```

it shows the following error when I check the service status:

```
uwsgi[31788]: /bin/sh: 1: date: not found
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344067) that all 2.x versions should support @(exec://date +%%F-%%H-%%M).
%%F-%%H-%%M should become YYYY-mm-dd-HH-MM format in the ini file.

I the reactions it says that it could be my path, but I am unsure about how to check my path inside an ini file, as I am using a virtualenv instead of my system environment.
My system setting:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64
Python 3.5.2
Virtualenv 15.1.0
uWSGI 2.0.15
Nginx 1.10.3
```

So my question is: How can I get uWSGI to generate a new log file using the system datetime inside the ini file?

ps. My flask app deploys succesfully when I leave out the @(exec://date +%%F-%%H-%%M) part.

Comment: Try using `/bin/date` instead of `date` and see if it helps

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. I shall update my question with the working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be because of PATH environment variable being different in the two environments. So you should be using absolute paths instead. Change

```
log-date = @(exec://date +%%F-%%H-%%M)
```

to

```
log-date = @(exec:///bin/date +%%F-%%H-%%M)
```